# How to circle numbers in a set in LaTeX?

Tags: overleaf, circles

Looking to circle some numbers in a set in LaTeX (Overleaf). Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{exercise}{Exercise}
\newtheorem*{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\newenvironment{solution}
  {\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}\begin{proof}[Solution]}
  {\end{proof}}

\begin{document}
\begin{problem}[4.50]
\normalfont Repeat the above exercise, but this time use $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$.
\end{problem}

\begin{solution}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item The generators of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ are $\langle 1\rangle, \langle 5\rangle, \langle 7\rangle$, and $\langle 11\rangle$.
    \item The divisors of 12 are $1,2,3,4,6$, and $12$.
        \item Order of 1: $\langle 0\rangle=\{0\}$
        \item Order of 2: $\langle 6\rangle=\{0,6\}$
        \item Order of 3: $\langle 4\rangle=\{0,4,8\}$
        \item Order of 4: $\langle 3\rangle=\{0,3,6,9\}$
        \item Order of 6: $\langle 2\rangle=\{0,2,4,6,8,10\}$
        \item Order of 12: $\mathbb{Z}_12=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

I want to circle certain numbers in the above sets, but am not sure how. Any help appreciated!

Comment: The `circledsteps` package can do that, using tikz.

Comment: I suspect the reason you haven't gotten responses more quickly is that you didn't provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). The MWE should start with `\documentclass`, include all relevant `\usepackage` commands, end with `\end{document}` and compile without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a TikZ solution. You will need to add `\usepackage{tikz}` to the preamble.

Define a macro `\cir` that takes as an argument the number to be circled:

```
\newcommand{\cir}[1]{\tikz[baseline]{%
    \node[anchor=base, draw, circle, inner sep=0, minimum width=1.2em]{#1};}}
```

The `minimum width` ensures that the circles will all be the same size. Note: if you try to circle a three-digit number the circle will grow. You can enlarge the minimum width if you want.

The code

```
Order of 12: $\mathbb{Z}_{12}=\{0,\cir{1},2,3,4,\cir{5},6,\cir{7},8,9,10,\cir{11}\}$
```

will produce the output
[image]

Comment: Can we apply this solution for the numbers in itemize?

Comment: @alper: Yes. Load the `enumitem` package, and then use `\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\cir{\arabic*}]`